# Change max/min value colorbar in treemap

Tags: python, plotly, treemap

This is an example treemap chart from plotly library

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")

print(np.average(df['lifeExp'], weights=df['pop']))
fig = px.treemap(df, path=[px.Constant("world"), 'continent', 'country'], values='pop',
                  color='lifeExp', hover_data=['iso_alpha'],
                  color_continuous_scale='RdBu',
                  color_continuous_midpoint=np.average(df['lifeExp'], weights=df['pop'])
                )
fig.update_layout(margin = dict(t=50, l=25, r=25, b=25))
fig.show()
```

These values should be min = 0 and max = 200 as below. Could you help me?
[image]

Comment: Duplicate [Colorbar minimum and maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70006188/colorbar-minimum-and-maximum)

Comment: @Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the plotly express treemap [documentation](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.treemap.html), you can pass a list `[min,max]` to the `range_color` argument:

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")

print(np.average(df['lifeExp'], weights=df['pop']))
fig = px.treemap(df, path=[px.Constant("world"), 'continent', 'country'], values='pop',
                  color='lifeExp', hover_data=['iso_alpha'],
                  color_continuous_scale='RdBu',
                  color_continuous_midpoint=np.average(df['lifeExp'], weights=df['pop']),
                  range_color=[0,200]
                )
fig.update_layout(margin = dict(t=50, l=25, r=25, b=25))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Big thanks for your answer ! I will try.